# Get the result of exists query in typescript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm trying to get the result of an exists query using typescript but I can't get the '1' or '0' of the object that the query is returning.

**code.ts**

```js
const rslt1 = query(`SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM patients WHERE cc=?)`, [params.ccInput]);
const rslt2 = query(`SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE specialty=?)`, [params.specialtyInput]);
(async () => {
        const frslt1:object = await rslt1
        console.log(frslt1, Object.values(frslt1))
        console.log(await rslt2)
})()
```

In the console I just get this:

```
[{ "EXISTS(SELECT * FROM patients WHERE cc='6465465465')": 0 } ] [ { "EXISTS(SELECT * FROM patients WHERE cc='6465465465')": 0 } ]
[{ "EXISTS(SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE specialty='Medicina general')": 1 } ]
```

I need the result of the query to do an if later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try to put the `query` call into your async function directly.

Try

```js
(async () => {
     const rslt1 = await query(`SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM patients WHERE cc=?)`, [params.ccInput]);
     const rslt2 = await query(`SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE specialty=?)`, [params.specialtyInput]);

     const frslt1: object = rslt1
     console.log(frslt1, Object.values(frslt1))
     console.log(rslt2)
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

How it worked for me was this:

**code.ts**

```js
(async () => {
  const rslt1:any = await query(`SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM patients WHERE cc=?)`, [params.ccInput]);
  const rslt2:any = await query(`SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE specialty=?)`, [params.specialtyInput]);
        
  const res1 = Object.values(rslt1[0])[0]
  const res2 = Object.values(rslt2[0])[0]
  console.log('result1:', res1, 'result2:', res2)        
})();
```

In console I get this:

```
result1: 0 result2: 1
```